# org.apache.hadoop.net.StandardSocketFactory not found

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

`configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.set("fs.default.name",NAME_NODE_URL);
                    hdfs = FileSystem.get(configuration);`

i am getting the below exception while using the code specified above,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Socket Factory class not found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.net.StandardSocketFactory not found
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getSocketFactoryFromProperty(NetUtils.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getDefaultSocketFactory(NetUtils.java:122)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getSocketFactory(NetUtils.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:477)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2433)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:166)
at com.arista.cvp.commons.db.HdfsClient.copyfromLocaltoHdfs(HdfsClient.java:55)
at com.arista.cvp.services.hadoop.HDFSService.copyFromLocal(HDFSService.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

could anyone help in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need either the hadoop-common-2.x jar on the classpath or the hadoop-core-1.x!